# Unable to define maxInstances when launching hub via Selenium 3.0.0 beta3

Tags: selenium, command-line-arguments, selenium-grid, jcommander

I've been using the `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar` and recently tried to upgrade to version `3.0.0-beta3`.

I'm attempting to spin-up a hub using the maxInstances parameter with the following command:

```
java -jar %~dp0DriverRepo\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar -role hub -port 5555 -maxInstances 9
```

This was working in `2.53.0`, but in `3.0.0-beta3` I'm met with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -maxInstances
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$2.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:224)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:138)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:67)
```

Apparently `maxInstances` is no longer a valid argument. I've searched for documentation regarding any changes that may have been made for use of the `maxInstances` parameter but I've had no luck. Has anyone else run into this issue, or is anyone aware of the proper way to spin-up a hub in `3.0.0-beta3` in a comparable way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember ever using an argument called `maxInstances`. I think that earlier there was no validation for invalid command line arguments but with Selenium 3, they perhaps enabled it.

Here's an example of why I feel my theory is true

Selenium 2.53.1 output wherein I am providing an invalid argument named `krishnan`

`selenium-server -role hub -krishnan 100
22:28:37.762 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2016-09-26 22:28:38.366:INFO::main: Logging initialized @758ms
22:28:38.378 INFO - Will listen on 4444
22:28:38.421 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2016-09-26 22:28:38.424:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2016-09-26 22:28:38.452:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@32eebfca{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-09-26 22:28:38.479:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6ec8211c{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}`

And here's how Selenium 3 beta version behaves for the same command line.

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta2.jar -role hub -krishnan 100
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -krishnan
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$2.setConfiguration(GridLauncherV3.java:216)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.java:130)
    at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:67)`

Selenium has never had any argument named maxInstances. It only had something called maxSession`.

The only usage for `maxInstances` has been within a node configuration file as shown [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json) which is passed to a Selenium node via the `-nodeConfig` argument. This represents the number of concurrent browser instances per browser flavor that can be opened up in a node.

Comment: I see. You're 100% correct. I've had a useless argument in there the whole time and thought it was required. I must have incorrectly pulled it from an unrelated example when I was first setting things up. Thanks for pointing that out!